# How to get check box value in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have two check boxes with same name, different id's and different values 
when I am clicking the button, I am getting two values

```
         <input name="t" class="job-filter styled" type="checkbox" name="clstype" value="C" id="CheckCls">
         <label class="label-checkbox" for="Cls" >Classes</label>

         <input name="t" class="job-filter styled" type="checkbox" name="clstype"  value="D" id="CheckDemo">
         <label class="label-checkbox" >Demos</label>

         ///////////////button id is Searchtype////
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Searchtype").click(function () {

        var clas: $("#CheckCls").val(),
        var Demo: $("#CheckDemo").val(),
       });
       });
```

Comment: Should the user be able to check both the search type and hit the button or should you restrict him to check any one between them?

Comment: @sagar, check my updated answer below. It has `json` as well variables and you can use whatever you need

Comment: @sagar is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the values correctly but the assignment is wrong.

You should have either like this,

```
var clas = $("#CheckCls").val();
var Demo = $("#CheckDemo").val();
```

Or like this,

```
var values = {
  clas: $("#CheckCls").val(),
  Demo: $("#CheckDemo").val()
};
```

If you want to retrieve the values only if they are selceted then you can check as below,

```
var clas, Demo;

if($("#CheckCls").is(':checked')){
   clas = $("#CheckCls").val();
}

if($("#CheckDemo").is(':checked')){
   Demo = $("#CheckDemo").val();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Searchtype").click(function () {

                 //var clas = $("#CheckCls").val();
                 //var Demo = $("#CheckDemo").val();
              
                 var values = {
                   clas: $("#CheckCls").is(':checked') ? $("#CheckCls").val() : undefined,
                   Demo: $("#CheckDemo").is(':checked') ? $("#CheckDemo").val() : undefined
                 };

                 var clas, Demo;

                 if($("#CheckCls").is(':checked')){
                    clas = $("#CheckCls").val();
                 }

                 if($("#CheckDemo").is(':checked')){
                    Demo = $("#CheckDemo").val();
                 }
              
              console.log(clas);
              console.log(Demo);
              console.log(values);
             });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="t" class="job-filter styled" type="checkbox" name="clstype" value="C" id="CheckCls">
                <label class="label-checkbox" for="Cls" >Classes</label>


                <input name="t" class="job-filter styled" type="checkbox" name="clstype"  value="D" id="CheckDemo">
                <label class="label-checkbox" >Demos</label>
<input type="button" value="Search" id="Searchtype" />
```

> Recommendations: You should follow the correct naming standard for
>   variables and properties. Most recommended is `pascal case` with
>   proper meaning.

Comment: i Need check box value ,not true or flase if check i need type like "C" or "D"

Comment: @sagar should the user be able to check both values or one at a time?

Comment: You can check the code by executing it. I will remove true/false part from the answer.

Comment: Okay, I have removed the true/false. You can let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: hai sir, yes ,but i need  values bcz i am sending check box value to my store procedure . with check box value i can  retrieve data from table

Comment: @sagar but you want the values to be sent to your stored proc only if its checked right? Also should you be able to send multiple values into your stored proc?

Comment: @sagar, values are already retrieved like this `var clas = $("#CheckCls").val();` above. Do you want to retrieve the value if its only checked?

Comment: @sagar I have updated the code for this by checking whether it is checked. This is what I have asked first but you said no and I deleted the code. Anyways I have added the same back now. You can execute the code and check whether this is what you are trying..

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** you are just checking the values of the checkboxes when you click on the button, So always it will give you the value no matter if its checked or not. You are not checking if its checked and then retrieving the value.

**Solution:** First check if the checkbox is checked and only then assign the value to your variable.

```
var clas= $("#CheckCls").is(':checked')? $("#CheckCls").val() || '';
var Demo= $("#CheckDemo").is(':checked')? $("#CheckDemo").val() || '';
```

Comment: hai @ aruna plz review ans , in need only one value , if check class ineed "c" but  i your ans is getting two valus

Comment: @sagar I am not aruna :) .. the above code will check if the checkbox i checked.. if its checked it will retrieve the value.. else it will assign a empty string that is `''`. The syntax I have used is called ternary operator.. its short form of if else..